# Return true if two booleans are true but also can be empty or not exists

Tags: javascript, refactoring, sapui5

I have a question about clear way of return `true` if two booleans are `true` but also can be empty. I mean there can be one or even non booleans and there it should be also true. So far I use:

```
var isSelectedM = true;
var isSelectedE = true;
if(this.getModel("info").getProperty("/dep")) {
    isSelectedM = this.byId("checkBoxM").getSelected();
}
if(this.getModel("info").getProperty("/sta")) {
    isSelectedE = this.byId("checkBoxE").getSelected();
}
return (isSelectedM && isSelectedE);
```

I see two problems here - I would like to start with both values as `false` and then probably change them to `true` and second it take so many lines. How can I do it more clear as I don't like my code now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use an array of arrays, subarrays containing the `getProperty` string and its linked `byId` string, and use an `every` test:

```
const items = [
  ['/dep', 'checkBoxM'],
  ['/sta', 'checkBoxE']
]
return items.every(([prop, id]) => (
  !this.getModel("info").getProperty(prop)
  || this.byId(id).getSelected()
);
```

Another benefit of this is that it's easily extendable to 3 or more items with very little additional code, just add to the `items` array.

Or, in ugly ES5:

```
var items = [
  ['/dep', 'checkBoxM'],
  ['/sta', 'checkBoxE']
];
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  var item = items[i];
  if (this.getModel("info").getProperty(item[0])
  && !this.byId(item[1]).getSelected()) {
    return false;
  }
}
return true;
```

As you can see, the code is a lot more verbose and harder to understand - I'd recommend using Babel and polyfills instead.

Comment: My bad - I didn't add that I use ES5 instead of ES6. Is there a way to easily change 'destructuring expression' and 'arrow function syntax (=>)'?

Comment: By far, the best option is to integrate Babel and polyfills into your build process so you can write and debug code in the latest and greatest version of the language, and transpile down to ES5 for obsolete browsers for production.

Comment: There is a type in `for`, should be i++, works like a charm and that's the much better code than this from question. Thank you!